# printer driver prints grayscale fonts as black

Tags: printing, fonts, grayscale

Canon iR-ADV 8285/8295 UFR II , Driver version 30.30.0.0
i am tried to print from ms word  and  ms access , the result is always black.
printing from adobe acrobat is good , and also printing to others printers
changing property in quality tab (graphics,photos, etc..) does not help.

Comment: If it's fine if you're using Adobe why do you suspect it's the printer drivers fault?

Comment: because in all other printers (bizhub, samsung ..) is fine

Comment: Maybe add some detail. As it is right now, for me, it reads like just Adobe is printing fine on other printers. If Adobe is the only application printing like you want in the first place it's not much of a surprise. What are you actually doing and what did your tests look like? Which were successful which were not?

Comment: Also, if you explicitly tell MS products to print in B&W, they will print greyscale as black sometimes.  I would make sure that's not an issue here.